# Encog - Training a neural network with Cross-validation methods and validating the training

Tags: java, validation, neural-network, cross-validation, encog

I would like to stop training a network once I see the error calculated from the validation set starts to increase. I'm using a BasicNetwork with RPROP as the training algorithm, and I have the following training iteration:

```
void trainCrossValidation(BasicNetwork network, MLDataSet training, MLDataSet validation) {

    FoldedDataSet folded = new FoldedDataSet(training);
    Train train = new ResilientPropagation(network, folded);
    CrossValidationKFold trainFolded = new CrossValidationKFold(train, KFOLDS);       
    trainFolded.addStrategy(new SimpleEarlyStoppingStrategy(validation));


    int epoch = 1;
    do {
        trainFolded.iteration();
        logger.debug("Iter. " + epoch + ": Erro = " + trainFolded.getError());
        epoch++;
    } while (!trainFolded.isTrainingDone() && epoch < MAX_ITERATIONS);

    trainFolded.finishTraining();
}
```

Unfortunately it is not working as expected. The method takes a huge time to execute and seems not to stop at the right moment. I wish the training be aborted at the exactly instant that the validation error begins to grow, that is, in the ideal amount of training iterations.

Is there a way that extract the validation data directly from a cross-validation folded instead of creating an another *MLDataSet* exclusively for validation? If yes, how to do this?

Which parameter should I use to stop the training? Can you show me the necessary modifications to do what is expected? How could I use cross-validation and *SimpleEarlyStoppingStrategy* together? I'm pretty confused

Thank you so much for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a couple of confusion points there.

- One thing is to stop training when the error start to increase in a different(!) set of data. This set of data is normally called *validation dataset*. That's valid for each training, i.e. for each loop that goes to the maximum epochs number (your do-while loop). For this, you need to keep track of the measure error on the last iteration: Run the network on the *validation dataset*, get the error and compare with that on the next epoch.
- Another thing is cross validation. Here, you train the network a number of times. From the whole bunch of training procedures, you *estimate* the goodness of the network. It is a more complex, more robust approach, with different variations. I like [this diagram](http://blog-test.goldenhelix.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/B-fig-1.jpg).
- Lastly: The fact that you stop training at the point where the error starts to increase doesn't mean that you found the *ideal amount of training* epochs. You may be caught in a local minimum, a common issue in these models.

Hope it helps you a bit  :)